# Google Spreadsheets: Working with data inserted from forms across tabs

Tags: data-structures, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm in great need of help. I've a form which asks basic questions and puts the results into rows of an existing spreadsheet.

Specific data from those responses are "promoted" to 2nd, 3rd and 4th tabs based on IF formulas on tabs 2+ checking the value of a pull down selection on in the corresponding row on each previous tab. (Waterfall)

My challenge is - forms data is inserted into a new row (Does not use existing) and if I set the pulldown value to "Approved" on the first tab, the formulas on the second tab which were contiguous now skip the row where the form data was automatically entered.

I suspect I need to learn how to properly use ArrayFormula, etc, but have not managed to fix this looking at existing examples combined with my IF statements.

Help is appreciated. [Sample is here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvnKlegx7T5bdHZjU1dSVjhFalEzMmtzZUhrVXdiYUE&usp=sharing) Safe to ignore the first and last tabs.

Thank you.

Comment: I am getting a perpetual "Loading..." when clicking your link (possibly due to numerous IF formulae ;-) ?). But you might want to look into FILTER (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197?hl=en) and/or QUERY (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for looking AdamL. The sheet loads OK for us, but there are a whack of IF formulae in it. Most of the IFs state if a certain column has a certain text string then take value from same row, other column. If will follow your links, thank you.

Comment: I do want to note though - my main issue right now is the way Forms Data is inserted into the spreadsheet. Using either formula, when rows of forms data are inserted as New Rows, it changes the formula on subsequent tabs to skip the row that was inserted thus my data does not propagate. I need the spreadsheet to use an existing row or continue the formula.... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using an open-ended range with ArrayFormula. For example, the formula on "2-Pipeline" in cell D3 could be:

```
=arrayformula(IF('1-IdeasReceived'!U2:U="Approved",'1-IdeasReceived'!L2:L, ))
```

The ranges `U2:U` and `L2:L` *should* pick up all rows in those columns, even after you've had forms submitted.

Since this is an ArrayFormula over column ranges, you only need it in cell D3; it will inject `CONTINUE` formulas down the rest of the column.

Warning: Your spreadsheet is combining dynamic row content (e.g. pulled from another sheet) with static content (e.g. "Environment, Health & Safety" column on "2-Pipeline" sheet). This is bound to result in misalignment if rows are added or deleted in the middle of the source data.

Comment: That is the formula aspect and it is beautifully simple. Thanks for providing an example.

Comment: Glad to help. I added several more examples in your shared spreadsheet, using absolute references for column U. That makes it easier to copy & paste the formula to other columns.

Comment: For the alignment issue and how forms inserts new rows; right now if a complete a form entry, it inserts data into row 233 in the tab 1-IdeasReceived. Formulas on subsequent tabs skip row 233 so I have the manual workaround of copying forms data into an existing row and Static & Dynamic row content stay aligned as static content is only added after the Dynamic content. This is the crux of the issue for me - if I could get the form to insert into an existing blank row, it would be good. Will test behaviour with arrays. Thanks.

Comment: I am still unable to control where the form inserts data into the spreadsheet and whether it adds a new row (Same formatting) or uses an existing. Thanks for the help thus far.